# Form load event Error loading config.properties file

Tags: java, properties

Guys thanks for time and help, I have a Java form for create and read property files for java.

I can write the file for example `config.properties`, but when I try to read, I get a bad string information 
    usename=a 
    path=/home/a/desktop

```
private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) { 

try { 
     InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream("config.properties"); 
     Properties rbReg = new Properties(); 
     rbReg.load(inStream); 
     DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
     DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss"); 
     Date date = new Date(); 

     text_box_smtp_server.setText(rbReg.getProperty("path")); 

     System.out.println(rbReg); 
} catch (Exception e) { 
     System.out.println("Error reading config file " + e); 
}
```

I want to fill the text with the contents of path for example: 
{u s e r n a m e = a , p a t h = /h o m e / a / D e s k t o p } 
and not { username=a,path=/home/a/Desktop }. The issue is only in the form of the text, I enter. Now what I have to check? or change?

Comment: I've read this several times & *still* do not understand the question.  What has this got to do with Swing?  Given you might use the same code for properties in a command line app. or a servlet, it seems - *nothing!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard `Properties` class does not support the functionality you are looking for. The `public synchronized void load(InputStream inStream)` method of `Properties` class expects the properties to be like in `Key`, `Value` paired.`Key` is a word without having any white spaces or `=` or `:`. Now if you want to keep your properties like bellow:

```
 u s e r n a m e = a
 p a t h = /h o m e / a / D e s k t o p
```

And you want to get "/home/a/Desktop" for the key "path", then you need to process it differently. The general idea is to make an InputStream to load into an instance of `Properties` class, skiping the white spaces from it. You can do that like bellow:

```
 InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
 BufferedReader br = null;
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 String line;
 br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
 while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
     int length = line.length();
     for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          if (line.charAt(i) != ' ') {
               sb.append(line.charAt(i));
           }
      }
      sb.append('\n');
 }
 InputStream inStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(sb.toString().getBytes());
```

All you need is to replace your first line inside the `try` block with the above code. Cheers!